# Strange lines in front of the document

Tags: hyperref

I want to create a document with the iodhbwm class. If I compile it the first time it works fine. But if I compile it a seccond time this lines apear at the begin of the document:

> id=1,dest=636861707465722E31,srcline=235C3333346265727363687269667420617566204562656E6
>   id=2,dest=73656374696F6E2E312E31,srcline=235C3333346265727363687269667420617566204562
>   id=3,dest=73756273656374696F6E2E312E312E31,srcline=235C333334626572736368726966742061
>   id=4,dest=73656374696F6E2E312E32,srcline=234C697374656E
>   id=5,dest=73756273656374696F6
>   id=6,dest=73756273656374696F6E2E312E322E32,srcline=23426569737069656C2065696E6572204
>   id=7,dest=73756273656374696F6E2E312E322E33,srcline=23426569737069656C2065696E6572204

The log file shows the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. l.22 \BKM@entry
>                  {id=1,dest={636861707465722E31},srcline={23}}{5C3333346265727...
>
> ?
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.22 \BKM@entry{i
>              d=1,dest={636861707465722E31},srcline={23}}{5C3333346265727...
> ```
>
> ?  ! Undefined control sequence. l.23 \BKM@entry
>                  {id=2,dest={73656374696F6E2E312E31},srcline={23}}{5C333334626...

I already contacted the author of the iodhbwm class. But he was not able to reproduce this error. Because of this he couldn't help me.

Now I think that it must be something else. I compile this code. It is an example from the documentation of iodhbwm.

```
\documentclass[
    load-dhbw-templates,
    auto-intro-pages = default,
    add-tocs-to-toc,
    debug,
    language = ngerman
]{iodhbwm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\dhbwsetup{%
    author                  = my name,
    thesis type             = SA,
    thesis title            = Verwendung von iodhbwm,
    student id              = 12345,
    institute               = Masterfind Factory faltfe,
    course/id               = Txxxx,
    supervisor              = Pikachu und Enton,
    processing period       = {01.01.17 -- 31.01.17},
    location                = Dreamtown
}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I am using MikTex 2.9.6941 on Windows 7 and I reinstalled MikTex two times.

Realy interessting is, that this lines disappear if I include hyperref. But normaly the class is doing this by it self.

Do somebody know why there are this lines?
Is somebody else able to reproduce this errors?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Just for further references I'll link this to https://github.com/faltfe/iodhbwm/issues/40

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the KOMA-classes now load bookmark if hyperref is detected. It is doing it in a `\AfterAtEndOfPackage` command. The `iodhbwm` class loads hyperref in `\AtEndPreamble`, so bookmark is loaded then too and this is too late for it: bookmark can't write to the aux-file the needed line

```
\providecommand\BKM@entry[2]{}
```

An simple document to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 }

\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\end{document}
```

Probably the only work-around is to prevent that bookmark is loaded:

```
\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 }

\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

A simple work-around is to load auxhook earlier:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox,auxhook}
\AtEndPreamble{
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 }

\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean. But wouldn't it help if I write `\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false, load-dhbw-templates, auto-intro-pages = default, add-tocs-to-toc, debug, language = ngerman]{iodhbwm}`

Comment: Well, thanks for your example. I'll try your solution soon. Would there be any issue if I load `bookmark` by default too?

Comment: bookmark loads hyperref. If you load it in the preamble it could be too early - at least the language will perhaps not correctly be passed by the class - this could affect \autoref.

Comment: @Ulrike The problem is not, that loading of `bookmark` it to late. The problem is, that loading `auxhook` (indirect via `hyperref`) via `\AtEndPreamble` does break this package and the `\AddLineBeginMainAux` code is never written to `aux` file—not only the lines added from `bookmarks` but all lines, e.g. the initial `\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}` of `hyperref`. `auxhook` is prepared to be loaded via `\AtBeginDocument` but not via `\AtEndPreamble`. So package authors should avoid this!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is not KOMA-Script. `bookmark` uses package `auxhook` to write the definition of a command into the `aux`-file. `\AddLineBeginMainAux` of `auxhook` has two different modes of working:

- If `\@beginmainauxhook` is `\relax`, it writes immediately to the `aux`-file.
- If `\@beginmainauxhook` is not `\relax`, `\AddLineBeginMainAux` adds its argument to `\@beginmainauxhook`.

If the package is loaded via `\AtBeginDocument` it initializes `\@beginmainauxhook` with `\relax`. If not, it initializes it to make itself `\relax` and tries to patch `\document` to add the execution of `\@beginmainauxhook` just after the opening of the main `aux` file.

Now, if you load `hyperref` via `\AtEndPreamble`, `hyperref` loads `auxhook` and `auxhook` cannot recognize, that patching of `\document` is to late. Because of this `\@beginmainauxhook` is never executed.

So the bug is, to load `hyperref` via `\AtEndPreamble` without loading `auxhook` before `\begin{document}` and without explicite executing `\@beginmainauxhook`. If you have a look into the `aux`-file you will find in this case also, that the line

```
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
```

that `hyperref` usually writes into the `aux`-file (immediately after the initial `\relax`) is missing. This is because of not executing `\@beginmainauxhook`.

So I would say, this is a bug in `iodhbwm` and it should be changed to load `auxhook` earlier. As a workaround you can load `auxhook` in the document preamble. Both would also bring back the line

```
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
```

into the `aux`-file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer from Ulrike the problem is a change within KOMAScript.

At the moment there is no support to pass a key value option which does not belong to the `iodhbwm` class itself.

There are to possibilities to fix this issue for now. The first one is loading `bookmark` in the preamble itself.

```
\documentclass[...]{iodhbwm}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

The second option is to use an internal command which is used to pass options to the base class.

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\iodhbwm@cls@baseclass@options}{bookmarkpackage=false}
\makeatother
```

A complete example would look like

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\iodhbwm@cls@baseclass@options}{bookmarkpackage=false}
\makeatother
\documentclass[
    load-dhbw-templates,
    auto-intro-pages = default,
    add-tocs-to-toc,
    debug,
    language = ngerman
]{iodhbwm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\dhbwsetup{%
    author                  = my name,
    thesis type             = SA,
    thesis title            = Verwendung von iodhbwm,
    student id              = 12345,
    institute               = Masterfind Factory faltfe,
    course/id               = Txxxx,
    supervisor              = Pikachu und Enton,
    processing period       = {01.01.17 -- 31.01.17},
    location                = Dreamtown
}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But please don't abuse the internal command.

Comment: Another possibility is to write yourself early enough `\providecommand\BKM@entry[2]{}` to the aux-file.

Comment: KOMA will implement a work-around.