# etoolbox + koma-script: Warning 'seems someone has broken package auxhook'

Tags: koma-script, etoolbox

I use `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndPreamble` to load the package `hyperref` at the end of the preamble. Doing so in a `koma-script` document results in the warning

```
Class scrartcl Warning: seems someone has broken package auxhook.



\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\begin{document}
Text here.
\end{document}
```

My question: Is this known/fixable/irrelevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading hyperref (and so auxhook) rather late. In earlier version of the KOMA-classes this could lead to an error (see e.g. [Strange lines in front of the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470525/strange-lines-in-front-of-the-document/470607#)), now scrartcl is trying to recover from this. You can avoid the warning by loading auxhook earlier:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{auxhook}
\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\begin{document}
Text here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since hyperref must typically be loaded last, is it safe to load auxhook at the very beginning of the preamble?

Comment: @tobiasBora auxhook is no longer needed and it will disappear at some time. Use the LaTeX hooks instead.

Comment: Ok thanks. But as I understand it LaTeX hooks have been introduced quite recently, so I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it now in a library that may be used on older LaTeX…

Comment: @tobiasBora I never needed auxhook in my life, are you sure that you need it?